# How to build Dojo into a single file, given a list of dependencies?

Tags: javascript, build, dojo

I have a simple Dojo application, that does only one `require` call, loading all the dependencies. The trouble is, while it is extremely simple, it still ends up loading ~100 files from server. I tried to solve that problem using Dojo build system, but seems I don't have a deep enough understanding.

So my question is - given a list of dependencies, like the following:

```
["dojo/parser",
 "dijit/registry",
 "dojo/dom",
 "dojo/on",
 "dojo/query",
 "dojo/dom-class",
 "dojo/request",
 "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox", 
 "dijit/form/Select",
 "dijit/form/NumberSpinner",
 "dijit/form/CheckBox",
 "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
 "dijit/Dialog",
 "dojo/NodeList-traverse",
 "dojo/domReady"]
```

how do I set up the build to create a single-file (or several-file, just not 100-file) dojo file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Dojo's `require()` loader, there are [build tools](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596516482/build_tools_comma_testing.html) that you can use to combine files and minify. According to the site, the build tools aren't included in an official release, so you'll have to get them from the [development version](https://github.com/dojo/util) (specifically, look in the `buildscripts` directory).

The Dojo documentation contains some info on its [build system](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/build/index.html#build-index) that you may also find useful.

**As a proof of concept**, here are the steps I took:

1. Go to the [download page](http://dojotoolkit.org/download/), and download the Source Dojo Toolkit SDK (it's the only one that contains the util scripts needed for a build).
2. Extract to a location (for the sake of this post, let's say it's `/opt/dojo-toolkit`).
3. *From the Dojo toolkit directory* (i.e. `/opt/dojo-toolkit`), run the build util: `./util/buildscripts/build.sh action=release htmlFiles=/path/to/my/index.html` (careful, this slowed my 5-year-old dual-core to a crawl)

Example of `index.html` (this one is exactly inside the `dojo-toolkit` directory):

```
...
<head>
    <script src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
    dojo.require("my.test");
    </script>
</head>
...
```

The `require()` call looks for nested modules (I couldn't get it to work with a top-level module), so in this case, I've got a `my` directory inside of `dojo-toolkit` which contains a `test.js` file. That file is the main "bootstrap" file which loads in all of the dependencies. I just put random `require()` calls in mine:

```
dojo.require('dijit.ProgressBar');
dojo.require('dijit.Tree');
```

And that should do it. Basically, running the build utility against your HTML file (the one that contains the reference to dojo.js) makes sure that all of the dependencies are found, starting from the top.

*Note*: the build system create a `release` directory with the built output, but it looks a little misleading at first - it appears to have minified each individual file, but if you look at your actual bootstrap file (`my/test.js`, in this case), it will be a combined, minified file with (I presume) everything you need to run your app.

---

Otherwise, if you're using AMD style `require()`'s (as in require.js), you can use its [optimization tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html). According to the site, it will:

1. Combine all dependent files (including require.js itself) into a single file. It analyzes the `require()` call to figure out which files it needs to combine.
2. Minify your JavaScript using either UglifyJS (default) or Closure Compiler.

Comment: I'm using dojo's require, and those docs for it's build system failed to help me :( I'm getting cryptic errors and strange output. Could you give a small snippet for how build profile should look and how should I invoke it?

Comment: @Rogach: Updated answer with a little guide.

Comment: I tried exactly as in your guide, and it gives me this error: `error(349) Missing prefix for top-level module. top-level module: fulmar` (I suspect that `fulmar` is my main .js file, which has `require()` in it).

Comment: Can you post that `index.html` somewhere? Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Seems I was using a bit another format for `require` call - the one like `require(["dojo/dom", ...], function(dom) {...})`. I'll try to experiment with it a bit more.

Comment: @Rogach: That seems to be an [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)-style require. Are you using require.js, or is that built-in to Dojo also?

Comment: It's built into Dojo, as far as I know.

Comment: @Rogach: Are you getting a specific error? In lieu of another option, you may want to try to use `require.js`'s optimization tool and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do the same thing and this is how I solved it.

If you read the documentation about how to create custom builds (http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/build/), in the Layers section they talk about creating custom layers. You can add all the modules you need there.  Here is an example of my custom layer file:

```
layers : {
"dojo/dojo" : {
    include : [
            "dojo/dojo",
            "dojo/_base/window",//
            "dojo/dom",//
            "dojo/dom-class",//
            "dojo/ready",//
            "dojo/store/Memory"
    ],
    customBase : true,
    boot : true
}
}
```

What this will do is build only those modules into dojo.js, along with the bootstrap loader so that you can load other modules on the fly.