# dojo internalize html templates

Tags: dojo

When using filter and pagination plugins for EnhancedGrid, the HTML templates for the same are loaded from dojox\grid\enhanced\templates.

Is there any way by which I can avoid the server requests for these HTML files by making them part of the Enhanced Grid's inline javascript?

Comment: Doesn't the Dojo build process merge them into the final file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution. Those struglling from this issue pls. note that there is bug with Dojo 1.7.1 and we need to use Dojo 1.8.3 and use internStrings option with the build command. You should see HTML files being interned in the build-report.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a custom dojo build that creates one js file as a result. follow this instructions from a previous QA:

[How to build Dojo into a single file, given a list of dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853876/how-to-build-dojo-into-a-single-file-given-a-list-of-dependencies)

**EDIT:**

The build should add those html files inline, but doesn't.  I googled a bit and found this link related to your problem:

http://grokbase.com/t/dojo/dojo-interest/121e536t64/enhancedgrid-filter-problem

It suggests a fix using this link

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Custom-build-including-CSS-and-HTML-files-td3536573.html

**Citation:**

---

If you are using the AMD style of module definition, then you can specify a text dependency like so:

```
define(["dojo/text!some/file.html", "other/module"],
function(template, otherModule){
    ...
    // to use the contents of the html file, treat template as if it were a normal string
    someNode.innerHTML = template;
    ...
});
```

The build system should automatically convert the text dependency to an inline string literal. Most Dojo files are already formatted to use this feature, but I can't account for dojox modules. I'm not sure whether similar functionality is possible with the dojo.require/dojo.provide system of dependency declaration.

---

Comment: No, doing a custom build doesn't internalize these HTML templates related to EnhancedGrid Filter plugin

Comment: I had already found that link using Google. The problem for me is to where should I place that piece of code(in my profile file for creating custom build or the HTML file where I am creating the enhancedgrid) which you have cited above and what should be the arguments to this function. I guess we use define([... when we want to create custom dojo module.

Comment: i think you need to place it where you define your enhancedgrid, so that the builder includes the html files in the build.After that you have to add the template to the filter plugin.